# How to test if a specific process ID is a terminal?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, proc

I'm writing a convenience script that will allow me to bring up an existing terminal upon pressing a keyboard shortcut, and spawn a new one if none currently exists.

Ideally, this would be agnostic to whatever terminal I was using, and also would not require me to maintain a lengthy list of binary names of popular terminals.

So far my searches on this topic have been fruitless, but assuming I have:

- The window ID
- The process ID
- The process environment and command line (through `/proc`)

How can I check if a given process is a terminal, vs say, a browser or a file explorer?

Answer (score 0):

There's not that much that distinguishes a terminal from any other application.

If you look through its open file descriptors via /proc/PID/fd, you will see the terminal emulator holding the "master" end of a pseudoterminal (usually opened through /dev/ptmx). Most other programs will not have that; they'd be connected to the other end (i.e. the actual terminal at /dev/pts/X or nothing at all).

Note that this will also include IDEs which have a terminal output pane active (e.g. VSCode showing build progress, or Neovim with a :terminal buffer), as well as programs like tmux or sshd.

Comment: Ooh interesting approach! That would require looking through fd/0 (stdin)? For my `konsole`, `readlink -f` shows it pointing to `/proc/2091343/fd/pipe:[7158826]`, which seems less tractable than I'd hoped

Comment: No, it will not be stdin for terminal emulators. (You're thinking of the "client" side of the pty.) The pty master will be one of the higher FDs (possibly several – each tab or split will have its own pty, so a separate master as well) but you can't really predict which; you have to check through all of them until you find a /dev/ptmx or /dev/pts/ptmx. (Best to compare by device major,minor rather than path.)

Comment: Got it! I'm peeking through lsof, limited to just /dev/ptmx, and it _seems_ like `konsole` has a connection through fd 16, which is unique to that (kded5 has 23 and thef*** has fd 6), though it seems like that just amounts to a magic number specific to `konsole`, no different than keeping lookups

Comment: (Note the `-f` option to the readlink command doesn't make sense in this context, you want to get the "raw" readlink result instead. Items under fd/ are magic symlinks and often their readlink() returns descriptive strings rather than paths. It's better to just `stat -L` or `[ x -ef /dev/ptmx ]` instead of looking at the link targets.)

Comment: Usually the fd number is irrelevant. It's whatever the app ends up with, after it opens all the connections and config files and stuff. The first few minutes of the terminal's lifetime might be deterministic, the rest not so much. (There's a fd for X11 or Wayland connection, one for dbus, maybe one for syslog, maybe some other short-lived sockets, and if you open who knows how many tabs and close some of them, the resulting FD table is pretty much random.) It might be 23, might be 17, for the same terminal on different days.